# Parse - Is this the correct method on how to use ACL and CLP to protect Users and other Objects

Tags: security, parse-platform

New to Parse, requesting feedback from community on whether I have set up Parse ACL and CLP security correctly....

It seems that Parse Security is all about building security layers on top off other security layers.

My concerns are that someone can use clientkey and access various objects and their data unless I lock it down correctly with ACL and CLP's....

Below, I have briefly outlined the three objects (_User, _Role and my FileUpload), the associated code and relationships.

The website I am building to test security will give a user the ability to create a user (in _User) and upload their files to FileUpload object.

**_User Object**

From the login page, I only want to allow user creation, user table is set up as follows :-

1. "public access" CLP set with "Create" permission only, rest are disabled.
2. CloudCode afterSave on user creation sets ACL on new user (code below).
3. CloudCode afterSave on user creation assigns role called "signed" to new user. (code below, role "signed" specifics described below)

In the CloudCode on User afterSave, code for items 2 and 3 above is below:-

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave(Parse.User, function(request) {
    if (!request.object.existed()) {
        Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();     
        var user = request.object;
        if (user.existed()) { return; }

        //2. set ACL on user
        var acl = new Parse.ACL(user);
        acl.setPublicReadAccess(false);
        user.setACL(acl);
        user.save();

        //3. assign role "signed" to user
        var roleQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
        roleQuery.equalTo("name", "signed");
        roleQuery.first().then(function(role) {     
            role.getUsers().add(user);
            return role.save();
        });  
    }
});
```

**_Role Object**

I created a role in _Role called "signed"

1. "signed" role ACL is set to "Master Key Only".
2. "public access" read & write CLP for _Role is disabled.
3. No CLP is enabled in _Role (see point 2), therefore, no CRUD is permitted,  but I am not sure how Parse allows "signed" role to work.

**FileUpload Object**

This object is set up so that the user can upload files to FileObjects only when logged in.

1. A pointer is present in FileUpload Object to User Object.
2. "public access" read & write CLP for FileUpload Object is disabled.
3. "signed" CLP for FileUpload Object added.
4. CLP permissions for role "signed" in FileUpload Object is set to "Find", "Create", "update" only, this permits ACL to be set to user objectId

To ensure that the user cannot see another user's fileuploads, I have set the following ACL on "FileUpload" afterSave.

```
 Parse.Cloud.afterSave("FileUpload", function(request, response) {
   var currentUser = Parse.User.current(); 
   if(!currentUser) {
        console.log('This is a user that is not logged in trying to upoad a file');
    } else if (currentUser) {
        var acl = new Parse.ACL(currentUser);
        acl.setPublicReadAccess(false);
        var user = request.object;
        user.setACL(acl);
        user.save();
        response.success();   
    } else {
         console.log('Cannot upload file');
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit late, but I'll give you my feedback either ways, since no one answered yet.

First, for the _User class, there's no need to set these ACLs, since a Parse.User by default has public read and  read and write permissions. Since you have a create only CLP there's no need to explicitly set the public access to false, unless you plan to change the CLP in the future.

Second, for the Parse.User afterSave I recommend using the masterkey only when you need it. Hence, you could remove the useMasterKey call at the beginning and only call it with roleQuery.first.

The FileUpload afterSave has a bug I believe: you want to set the request.object's ACL, rather than the user's ACL.

Other than that it looks good.